# When requesting a Header file from HTTP , If content-Length is available then no keep-alive shown

Tags: http, connection

When I send a header request to some servers  I have two situations , 
either
1) no content-length response is available which indicated a chunked data, if so then Connection : keep-alive response is available 
2) Content-Length is available , however Connection: keep-alive is not,

In the second case does that mean the connection is dropped or is it kept alive with default timeout and max connection settings , thats is why it is not sent.

I really need to make sure the connection is kept alive , for further testing.

I send a Connection : keep-alive every time I make a request ,

Please Help??

Comment: The decision to keep a connection alive is up to the server. A client can request that it be left open, but the server makes the final decision if it should be - otherwise it'd be trivial to overload a server with open-and-never-will-closed connections.

Answer (score 2):

For HTTP/1.1 connections, [keep-alive is the default](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1).  Because of this, the "Connection: keep-alive" header is only useful for HTTP/1.0 connections.  So unless the client specifically asks for "Connection: close", the server will (usually) keep the connection open for further requests.